# Ubuntu 20.04 Ibus Anthy Japanese input stopped working

Tags: 20.04, ibus

Since I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 ibus-Anthy input stopped working.  The `ibus-daemon` is running, Anthy is installed, the input-switcher comes up, the Anthy control-panel thing appears (in Anthy mode) but the Romaji input is never converted.

I should be able to switch keybaord to Anthy, start typing `fu bu pu` and have that automatically come up as `ふ ぶ ぷ`.  But it just stays in the Latin alphabet.

[image: bad_anthy]

Any advice much appreciated.  I'm using Cinnamon Desktop, but it fails the same way using whatever the Ubuntu default is (Unity?).  I can't do my homework like this.

EDIT: It's not just LibreOffice, gnome-terminal, gEdit, etc. are all broken too.

Comment: Have you set _Input mode_ to e.g. Hiragana?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson - Oh, that was it. Thanks!  Somehow it was switched back to `Latin`.  **Note:** I also needed to logout+login for this change to take any effect.   Just changing the setting did not show a change.